# bash avoid "command not found" error echo

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I have developed a script, which shows me the versions of my tools with one command.

Code: [link to github repo](https://github.com/m1well/versions/blob/master/versions.sh)

Result Snippet:

```
###############################################
########## versions (alphabetically) ##########
###############################################
bash:          3.2.57(2)-release`<br>
java:          1.7.0`<br>
/export/home/zmbf8bl/.mw701/10_scripts_tools/versions/versions.sh: line 137: npm: command not found`<br>
/export/home/zmbf8bl/.mw701/10_scripts_tools/versions/versions.sh: line 146: node: command not found`<br>
zsh:           4.3.6`<br>
###############################################
```

The special behaviour should be, that if a tool isn't available the script don't print anything about it. On Windows and macOS that works, but not on Linux.
Linux prints out e.g. `npm: command not found`.

How can I avoid this error  message and just print nothing if a tool (e.g. npm) isn't available on my machine???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't post links, post your code as text.

Comment: Err, what if you check if a command exists before calling it?

Answer (score 2):

just replace

```
2>&1
```

in your code with

```
2>/dev/null
```

in general，command not found error is print to stderr
and when you do version check, redirect stderr to /dev/null
then you will get only stdout infomation

Comment: The problem with ignoring all error messages is that if the program runs but fails in some other way you will loose the error messages and you won't know why it didn't work.

Comment: how about using grep -v, like this,  gulp -v 2>&1 |grep -v 'command not found'

Comment: Could use `grep -v` but personally I try to avoid unnecessary child processes (`grep` is an external program, not a shell builtin).

Comment: but I saw grep is used many times in your code,  like <<< version="$(echo $(bash --version 2>&1 | grep -i 'bash' | cut -d " " -f 4))" >>>

Comment: @LiQlang.Feng - not in my code, I'm trying to the question.  I would not use `grep` or `cut` for that, I would use bash string expansions.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the command exists in your $PATH, do

```
checkCommand () {
    if command -v "$1" >/dev/null; then
        : # OK command exists
    else
        echo >&2 "$1: no such command"
        return 1
    fi
}

if checkCommand npm; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, you could explicitly use something like the `type` command, if you knew the full path you could test if the file exists and you have execute access (`-x`), or you could just use an `if`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! npm arg1 arg2
   if (( ? != 127 ))
   then
      echo "npm failed $?"
   fi
fi
```

Bash returns 127 if the command is not found.

EDIT:  You will still get the `command not found` error message, but it won't stop your program.  The problem with ignoring all error messages is that if the program runs but fails in some other way you will loose the error messages and you won't know why it didn't work.